# Swift Full Screen Navigation Push Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to achieve something similar to Facebook's way of presenting the comments view controller for a specific post. In below picture one can see, that the pushed new view controller is presented "full screen" (for the lack of a better way of describing the behaviour). It seems to me like some kind of modal segue rather than a push one. When trying to recreate that in my own app I can't achieve that the whole navigation bar is included in the presentation segue. Only the view inside the presentation hierarchy is changed. I want the second view controller to be entirely white (the view as well as the navigation bar) but both view controllers should have the default swipe-to-go-back behaviour. How can that be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What they're probably doing is hiding the navigation bar.

You can achieve the same effect if you set `navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true` (can also do it on navigation bar in UINavigationController from the storyboard), make a regular `show` segue and just display it using `performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextScreen", sender: nil)`. You can then make your own UI logic for displaying back buttons etc.

Comment: That worked, but now the parent view controller does have its navigation bar hidden as well. How can I switch it back on so there is no "flickering"?

Comment: @pmax1: you'll have to add another UINavigationBar to your UI, set your viewcontroller as delegate and implement `UIBarPositioningDelegate`, in particluar `func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition` to extend it under the status bar on iPhone X, returning .topAttached